Ecology in R: Error in mgcv package "Error in eval(family$initialize) : values out of range"
I'm trying to fit a model in R which shows how depth and sediment type influence seagrass density (response) and collected a dataframe with about 5000 rows. For ease of data collection, we have discrete values of seagrass density set in 5 categories, from 1 to 5 (each representing a band of percent coverage). There are no NA values in the data frame. There will be spatial autocorrelation in the data so I added a smooth term with the latitude and longitude to account for this.
I'm using the OCAT family with a logit link to account for the ordinal type data and set theta to 4 (since there are 4 "steps" between the discrete values of density). Let me know if any of this is incorrect.
Here is my model:
model_gam_spatial <- gam(Density ~ s(Latitude, Longitude) + Depth + Substrate.type, 
                         data = seagrass_clean, family = ocat(theta = 4, link = "logit"))

I keep getting this error message when I try to run the model
"Error in eval(family$initialize) : values out of range"

Can any suggest what I'm doing wrong? Or any other tips? If there is a better kind of model which would be suitable for my data also please let me know. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

You are cofusing the theta with the R parameter. Try with R = 4.

You need to set ocat()'s argument R to the number of groups in your response, to 5 in your case as you have 5 groups. theta needs to be a vector of length R-2 cut points on the latent variable, if you supply it. If you leave it at the default (NULL), mgcv will estimate the R-2 cut points for you, which is typically what you want to have happen.

I'm now getting this error message. "Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : Value -1.5 out of range (0, 1)". It may have something to do with the logit link. This is what my code looks like now: model_gam_spatial <- gam(Density ~  s(Latitude, Longitude) + Substrate.type + Depth,
data = seagrass_clean, family = ocat(R=5, theta = NULL, link = "logit"))

Also, my data is highly skewed with most results for density = 0. In case 0s don't work with a logit link, I added 1 to response variable so it is now a scale of 1-5, as an integer.

Update: After amending the model to include R = 5 and theta = NULL, I was still getting an error message. The solution is that you cannot use the logit link function in the OCAT family. This model below worked for me:
model_gam_spatial <- gam(Density ~  s(Latitude, Longitude) + Substrate.type + Depth,
data = seagrass_present, family = ocat(R=4))
